# /////how to pass props variable or function to slot Vue 2.x?

Tags: vuejs2, customization, slot

I want to customize the slot to pass variables or functions to the slot template.
For example, there is a named icon-add slot and its code looks like inside item-view.vue.
And, I want to pass one string variable called `serialKey`.

```
<template >              
<slot name="icon-add" :serialKey="s_serialKey" > </slot>
```

...

How to get it from here?

```
<button
type="button"
class="json-editor__btn json-editor__btn_icon"
>
<slot name="icon-add">
    <span class="btn-icon btn-icon_add" title="Add">+</span>
</slot>
```

I searched it on google but did not find the right case for me.

Please help me to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: You're probably looking for [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

Comment: @StevenB. I am not familiar with Vue yet. So can you guide me how to update it above my code?

Comment: Btw, the above 2 code blocks are inside same file, no exist the separate component for slot now.